# How to get fopen to timeout properly?

Tags: php, sockets, fopen

I have the following snippet of php code

```
if($fp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 1); 
    stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

}
$info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
```

I'd like the request to timeout after 1 second. If I put a `sleep(20)` in my `$url` that I'm reading, it just waits the whole 20 seconds and never times out. Is there a better way to do timeouts with `fopen`?

If I use `ini_set('default_socket_timeout',2)` above that code it times out properly but `$info` then becomes null so ideally I'd like to use the stream functions.

Comment: What do you expect $info to be when there is a connection timeout?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [stream_context_create()](http://docs.php.net/function.stream-context-create) and the [http context option `timeout`](http://docs.php.net/context.http). But `fopen()` will still return false if a timeout occurs, and `stream_get_meta_data()` won't work.

```
$url = 'http://...';
$context = stream_context_create( array(
  'http'=>array(
    'timeout' => 2.0
  )
));
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
if ( !$fp ) {
  echo '!fopen';
}
else {
  $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
  var_dump($info);
}
```

Comment: the only issue with that is that context's weren't added until php5 and the code I'm writing unfortunately needs to be php4 compatible :(

Comment: The manual says PHP 4.3.0 so you should be good to go,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: i've just tried "timeout" , but when i chose timeout = 2 , actually take 4 seconds to timeout, if timeout = 15, actually take 30 seconds to timeout. why?

Comment: Same result here - timeout will be doubled.

Comment: The "doubling timeout" has been [reported to the PHP project](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48280), where it is said to be "not a bug". A maintainer replies "the value is used both for connection timeout, and then again for read timeout".