# PHP fopen() increase the time out limit?

Tags: php

I created script like this

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("list1.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {



$file = fopen("http://$urldhara1/app.php?name=$line","r");


 fclose($file);

    }
?>
```

it works fine.this code execute the process in my server.
sometimes it take 10 minutes to complete.
due to this before the one process complete the next process start.
i thinks because of the timeout limit i try

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

but it does not help.
so sir what should i do for increase the timeout of fopen.
or i am doing something wrong?
what should i do??
in my script the before completion of the one process the another preocess start what should i do please help me.

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure fopen is the one blocking?

Comment: one blocking?? i am just neebie

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what happens? You open the script via browser and it times out? Does the script work if you run it from command line? What do you mean with next process starting, who starts it? You mean you open the script again while the first one is still not finished? And what are you doing inside the code that takes 10 minutes to finish? Please update your question.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511225/how-to-get-fopen-to-timeout-properly and the PHP manual at http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php .